# Lazy load reload images if I press back button on browser

Tags: jquery, jquery-lazyload

I have use jQuery lazy load http://jquery.eisbehr.de/lazy for while.. on my web http://www.xaluan.com 
but I think it not perfect when every time I go to other page then go back then forward.

The script will reload all images, I have check network in inpect element of Chrome and Firefox. I can see it make calls to server again, that is not what I want.

Any one have solution for caching this when click back, forward button
I have thinking about api history browser. but have no idea how to use it with back and forward button on any pages.

Comment: Please show a piece of code you tried. I have an idea

Comment: I have no ideal at all. just using lazy load on my web .. http://www.xaluan.com you could go there.. then click any link on it then click back on browser button.. will se it will reload again .. that is bad .. hope someone have solution

Comment: You phrase your question in reverse. I understood that you wanted to bind the forward button to reload the images again. While you want the pictures to keep in memory and avoid being charged. That's right ?